# "Microsoft Visual Studio is waiting on an internal operation to complete"

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I get the Microsoft VS Delay Notification pop up consistently when I am trying to attach the debugger to a remote process (Native only, with no authentication). The process runs as a service on the remote machine, but Visual Studio (2005) seems to have no problem with that when it's running as a service locally.

I've loaded the symbols correctly (as in specified the right directory under Tools\Options\Debugging\Symbols), but this doesn't seem to help.

I've tried starting VS 2005 in Safe Mode, but that doesn't seem to make a difference either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and used ProcMon util to look at waht my devenv were doing.
In my case it was waiting for loading symbols. So  you you should check your Env. variable _NT_SYMBOL_PATH and if there is cached symbols if no -  all this time your VS is waiting for downloading it.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is you have many currently set or lingering (invalid) breakpoints.
Try clearing all the breakpoints and see if it helps.

There are more possible solutions here:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/498240/microsoft-visual-studio-is-waiting-for-an-internal-operation-to-complete

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had just two breakpoints at the time. I did go through that thread before, but the conclusion drawn was that there was a whole suite of performance problems which gave that generic error, and that upgrading to 2012 is the solution. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this problem when I turned on both native and managed debugging on a single application.
Turning off the native debugging fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that helped me is updating the package. Open the solution that is having this "waiting for internal operation to complete" then Go to Tools - Nuget Package Manager - Package Manager Console. Then run "Update-Package". After the update, I was able to close and open the solution with no problems. Hope this helps your issues.

Answer (score -1):

I had the similar problem and it occurs because of the variable expression I created.

For example:

```
variable1  =  variable1 - variable2 (gets warning)
variable1  =  variable2 - variable3 (No Issues)
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, did a lot of googling tried several things but didnt solve the problem. Finally I used processexplorer to check the devenv process and found there is a child process for devenv.exe, it was cmd.exe and it has another child process node.exe. So I went to Programs and Features and uninstalled Node 1.1 VS 2013 extension and Node package manager. It took quite some time to uninstall it even though I am using i7 quadcore processor with 16 GB RAM it took almost close to 1 hour to uninstall these two sofwares from my laptop. And this solved the issue.